# Jplayer not changing track

Tags: jplayer

Having an issue with Jplayer changing a track when a link is clicked.  It still plays the demo track from the player and doesn't play harry.mp3 or harry2.mp3

```
<tr><td>Tracklist:</td></tr>
<script>$('#mp31').click(function()
`{  $("#jp-player").jPlayer({   ready: function () {    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "/harry.mp3",    });   },   swfPath: "/js",   supplied: "mp3"  }); });` </script>

<tr><td>1. </td><td><a href="" id="mp31">Test</a>Friend</a> (Techno)</td></tr>
<script>$('#mp32').click(function(){  $("#jp-player").jPlayer({   ready: function () {    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "/harry2.mp3",    });   },   swfPath: "/js",   supplied: "mp3"  }); }); </script><tr><td>2. </td><td><a href="" id="mp32">Test</a>Enemy</a> (Ambient)</td></tr>
```

Can anyone please help, it's doing my head in.

CP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two instances of jplayer. According to your scenario, you should have only one. Also, take care of your typos. Finally, you could try with something like this:

```html
<tr>
    <td>Tracklist:</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td><a class="song" href="http://my-website.com/mp31.mp3" id="mp31">Test</a>Friend</a> (Techno)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td><a class="song" href="http://my-website.com/mp32.mp3" id="mp32">Test</a>Enemy</a> (Ambient)</td>
</tr>
```

The code above show you a list of `<a>` elements with the mp3 url that you want to play, so, by this way yo can update the player once the click them:

```js
<script>
    $("#jp-player").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "/harry.mp3"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "/js", supplied: "mp3"
    });

    $('.song').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // get the song url from the href attribute
        var song = $(this).attr('href');

        $("#jp-player").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: song
                });
            },
            swfPath: "/js", supplied: "mp3"
        });
    });

</script>
```